# How to set objects around circle correctly on UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I've write some code to place objects around circle that locate on center of the Custom view, but it not perfectly around the circle. I don't know where of the code is wrong.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
func createObjectsAroundCircle() {

    let center = CGPointMake(bounds.width/2 ,bounds.height/2)
    let radius : CGFloat = 100
    let count = 20

    var angle = CGFloat(2 * M_PI)
    let step = CGFloat(2 * M_PI) / CGFloat(count)

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    // set objects around circle
    for var index = 0; index < count ; index++ {
        let x = cos(angle) * radius + center.x
        let y = sin(angle) * radius + center.y

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "\(index)"
        label.frame.origin.x = x
        label.frame.origin.y = y
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
        label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        label.sizeToFit()

        self.addSubview(label)
        angle += step 
    }
}
```

Comment: The origin of your label's frame is its top left corner.  That's why your label text appears outside, on the bottom right quadrant, and inside in the top left quadrant.

Comment: simply set those x and y points to center of label, after setting a temp frame

Comment: @PetahChristiani Thank you, I really forgot that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your code is working alright, just calculation logic is wrong. You should try to set `label.center` instead of `label.frame.origin`, or

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "\(index)"
label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)
label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
label.sizeToFit()
label.frame.origin.x = x - label.frame.midX
label.frame.origin.y = y - label.frame.midY
```

Remember to `sizeToFit()` before changing frame or setting `center` of the label. Good Luck!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CircleLayout/Introduction/Intro.html

Download sample code and have a look.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

For convenience purposes, both Masa S-AiYa question logic + Fahri Azimov answer have been combined:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width/2, y: bounds.size.width/2)
let radius: CGFloat = 100
let count = 20

let pi = Double.pi
var angle = CGFloat(2 * pi)
let step = CGFloat(2 *  pi) / CGFloat(count)

let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(pi * 2), clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20)

// Set objects around the circle
for index in 0..<count {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "\(index)"
    label.font = font
    label.textColor = .black
    // Remember to call 'sizeToFit()' before changing 'frame' or setting 'center' of the label!
    label.sizeToFit()
    
    // Position
    let x = cos(angle) * radius + center.x
    let y = sin(angle) * radius + center.y
    let midX = label.frame.x + label.frame.width / 2
    let mixY = label.frame.y + label.frame.height / 2
    
    label.frame.origin.x = x - midX
    label.frame.origin.y = y - mixY
    
    addSubview(label)
    angle += step
}
```